# Uploading images to GAE Blobstore from Java servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

Currently my web application encodes user uploading images to base64 and sends to servlet as POST payload. From GAE Java servlet, I would like to some how decode base64 image into a byte array or some sort and upload to blobstore to obtain a URL to respond back to the browser.

Blobstore API official documentation web page says uploading right from Java is deprecated now. What can I do to achieve what I want to do all in GAE? Right now my work around solution is using Cloudinary api to upload to their server and obtain a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the images in GCS using the [AE GCS client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/).
You can create a serving URL for that image via the [ImageService API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#getServingUrl-com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions-).